# Searching in json field by Entity Framework

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've developed a web app with ASP.NET MVC which uses Entity Framework as ORM.
One of my defined entities may have different and various attributes so I decided to save these attributes in a text column as JSON format in database.

For example look at this :

[image: Screenshot]

Consider each entity may have all or any or none of these attributes, also users can define new types of these attributes.

For example I want to search all records which have a `Price_T` attribute with a value bigger than 2000.

I can parse these texts as JSON in code but I want to know does Entity Framework have a built-in mechanism to search inside text columns like this (text with JSON format)? Or is there any solution or a best practice for doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't something like MongoDB better fit your data requirements?

Comment: EF doesn't have anything built-in, but your database might have something you can use through Raw SQL Queries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql.  EG Sql Server has OPENJSON for cracking JSON on the server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Use [JsonProperty.EFCore](https://github.com/maxchistt/JsonProperty.EFCore). You can install it as a nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonProperty.EFCore).

Example:

```cs
using JsonProperty.EFCore;

//Create product
var product = new Product() { Name = "Car" };

//AddRange
product.Attributes.AddRange(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    //You can add values ​​of different types if the base type is object 
    {"MaxSpeed",300},{ "Engine capacity",3.5}, { "ElectroCar",false }
});

//Add
product.Attributes.Add("Color", "Red");

//Edit
product.Attributes.Edit(attrs=>{
    attrs["Color"] = "Blue";
    return attrs;
});

//Entity model
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Json container property. Same type as JsonDictionary<string,object>
    public JsonDictionary Attributes{ get; set; } = new();
}
```

In your case, if you already have not strict typed json, do this on program starts:

```cs
using JsonProperty.EFCore;
//Setup serialization setings
Settings.JsonSettings.StrictTypeSerialization = false;
```